# Can't retag a question though have sufficient rep point

Tags: support, tags

I am trying to retag [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/logic-behind-a-bejeweled-like-game) but it says I don't have enough privilege to do so. Retag question requires 500 rep point and mine is higher then that.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exact message are you getting? Can you paste the text here or screenshot it?

Are you clicking the "retag" option and not "edit"?

Comment: oh, not that i noticed for retagging there is retag button. I was trying to do this with 'edit'. Why there are 2 different functionality, when in edit mode I am allowed to edit the tagging text box?

Comment: until you have 2000 rep, your edits have to be reviewed by other users.. but at 500 rep tag-only edits do not.