# Why is my recent "retag" privilege not available?

Tags: bug, reputation, tags

At 500 reputation, one earns the privilege of retagging.  It is allegedly an alternative to editing a post (which requires edit approval), yet I have never seen this retagging option.  The "Retag" page claims there is a "retag" menu option under the post.  There is none for me, nor anywhere else I can see (below tags, on the edit page, above the post, near the profile picture).

So my question is... is this a bug?  Am I missing some obvious option (in my profile, say) to enable this functionality?  Is my 546 reputation not enough to enable this privilege I've received notifications claiming I should have?

To be perfectly clear, this [question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/why-are-the-edit-and-retag-links-missing-from-this-post) is not the problem I'm encountering, as I can see "edit" on every post, but never "retag".  This [question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/cant-retag-a-question-though-have-sufficient-rep-point) is also not the problem, as I understand there should be a "retag" option, but all that appears is "share", "edit", and "flag".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Kill the Retag option, use just Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit)

> Retag is gone. It has ceased to be. The "please go back and click the retag link instead of edit" message is gone. We will (not) miss it.
>
> Editing tags only will result in the same behavior as retag, except
>   for the message (low enough rep will put it in review queue for
>   suggested edits, having the retag questions privilege will make it a
>   regular edit.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179401

Comment: Thank you!  The description of the privilege just hasn't been updated to reflect that change, then, which is really confusing.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Haven't figured out how to change the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what might be the case. But I always use "edit", then I simply add or remove tags.. Works for me :)

Comment: I was under the impression that using "edit" requires approval, while the "retag" option does not.  At least, this is what the specific privilege page says here:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions

Comment: Today I have edited a question, adding an additional tag. Haven't known that it wasn't approved. My bad :)

Comment: Quite all right.

Answer (score 0):

The retag option is hidden until you hover over the tags themselves.  It's not in the section at the bottom.

[image]

At least, that's for me.

Comment: Shucks, I was hopeful this was the problem, but it wasn't.  =(   Unless I'm hovering "incorrectly" (is that even possible?), this doesn't seem to be the case for a non-mod, or at least not for me.  Hovering simply shows a small black box with the Wiki summary, link to the faq, top users, etc.  No "edit tags" option.

Comment: You need 10000 reputation for this.